# mysql insert values not updating after some hours?

Tags: java, mysql

I am working on a project in which a java client continuously updates the database entries but after some hours of working it's not updating into database without throwing any error ??

database :mysql
Java thread is running in eclipse which always listen and updates the entries 
eclipse :kepler

what changes required in configuration of mysql ?

Comment: You'll have to provide more information than that.

Comment: can you add some more detail please? Code, DB structure, expected result etc etc. Not enough to go on here.

Comment: Check you "autocommit" status or call commit?!

Comment: @Tyco autocommit status is on mode

Comment: What i exactly want is how to extend  the timeout period of mysql server for accepting requests and make transaction threads alive for long time ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem we need see to issue timeout period of mysql and closing jdbc connections   correctly   which was opened in programs like ajax pages ..

1)
 `"  put these lines in /etc/mysql/my.conf
    under 
    [mysqld]
    #waiting time increase to 24 hour------------
    interactive_timeout=86400
    wait_timeout=86400   "`

This way increase your inactive time to 24*60*60 seconds=1 day

2)

In the ajax pages the data continuously updates to the page by opening the database connection ,we should close this connection after use otherwise it will become leak and total heap will occupy finally blocks you to run the java application

To analyse the leaks use any heap analyser tools example eclipse workbench memory analyser(mat)

download from this link http://www.eclipse.org/mat/downloads.php

and analyse the heap fix the leaks

This steps solved by problem